# How to make dropdown menu same width as each <li> in nav?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu, but for some reason, I cannot find a way to make its width the same as each `<li>`in nav.

```css
/* GENERAL STYLES */
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    background-image: url("../img/paven.png");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "nevis";
    src: url("../fonts/nevis.ttf");
}

/* MENU */
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #333;
}

nav > div {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

nav > div > ul {
    float: left;
}

nav > div > ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    height: 40px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

nav > div > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;    
    line-height: 35px;
}

nav > div > ul > li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #70B231;
}

/* SUBMENU */
nav > div > ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #70B231;
}
```

```html
<!-- MENU -->
<nav>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Content</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Requirements</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Languages</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Frameworks</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Less</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sass</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Flexbox</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Instructor</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

As you can see, I've tried setting a width for each `<ul>`, but they are not well aligned to the `<li>` they belong to:

[image]

I would like to achieve something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, I've edited a few thing.

I removed the `padding` on the main menu `li` element and placed it on the `a` instead so the submenu can take the full width.

Added `postition: relative;` to the main menu `li` so the submenu `postition: absolute` will be relative to the main menu item

Made the submenu full width with `width 100%` and removed the list styles.

added some `padding` to the submenu `li`

```css
/* GENERAL STYLES */
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../img/paven.png");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "nevis";
  src: url("../fonts/nevis.ttf");
}

/* MENU */
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #333;
}

nav>div {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

nav>div>ul {
  float: left;
}

nav>div>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

nav>div>ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

nav>div>ul>li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #70B231;
}

/* SUBMENU */
nav>div>ul>li>ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #70B231;
  list-style: none;
}

nav>div>ul>li>ul>li {
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- MENU -->
<nav>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Content</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Requirements</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Languages</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Frameworks</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Less</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sass</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Flexbox</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Instructor</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```